# Bubble sort function in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to create a function, bubble, which takes in a (listof Num) and return the list after 1 pass of bubble sort. Following is my code.

```
(define (check-numbers-size a b)
  (cond
    [(empty? b) (cons a b)]
    [(> a (list-ref b 0)) (append (list-ref b 0) (append a (rest b)))]
    [else (cons a b)]))


(define (bubble L)
  (foldr (lambda (x y) (check-numbers-size x y)) '() L))


(bubble (list 5 2 4 7 1))
```

When I attempt to run it, it is giving me the following error

```
append: expects a list, given 7
```

However I thought that b IS a list given that I specified an empty list as the base of this bubble function. What did I do wrong?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The function `append` expects two lists as input.

```
> (append (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5))
(list 1 2 3 4 5)
```

The function `list-ref` extracts one element from a list:

```
> (list-ref (list 10 11 12 13 14) 2)
12
```

In your code, you have the expression:

```
(append (list-ref b 0) ...)
```

The problem here is that `(list-rf b 0)` returns an element not a list.
To construct a new list from an element and a list, you need to use the list constructor `cons`.

```
(cons (list-ref b 0) ...)
```

Note that you have a similar problem in the expression

```
(append a ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right that `b` happens to be a list here. But what about the other arguments to `append`, like `a` or `(list-ref b 0)`?

Its easier to think about these things if you put signatures on your functions, to show what they take as arguments and what they return. You said that `bubble` takes a (Listof Num) and returns the list after 1 pass of bubble sort. Why not write that down in the code?

```
;; bubble : (Listof Num) -> (Listof Num)
;; returns the list after 1 pass of bubble sort
(define (bubble L)
  ...)
```

You should do the same for your helper function, `check-numbers-size`. You said that `b` is a list:

```
;; check-numbers-size : ??? (Listof Num) -> ???
```

And since you use `(cons a b)` within the body, I'm guessing you meant for `a` to be a `Num` so that the function returns a `(Listof Num)`.

```
;; check-numbers-size : Num (Listof Num) -> (Listof Num)
(define (check-numbers-size a b)
  ...)
```

Now that we know that `a` is a `Num` and `b` is a `(Listof Num)`, we can figure out what the arguments to `append` are. There are two `append` calls which might be the cause of the problem:

1. `(append a (rest b))`
2. `(append (list-ref b 0) (append a (rest b)))`

Is (1) okay? If `a` is a `Num` and `b` is a `(Listof Num)`, then (1) is trying to call `append` on a `Num` and a `(Listof Num)`. It's the first argument, `a`, that's the problem, not `b`. It looks like you meant to use `cons` instead.

Is (2) okay? If `b` is a `(Listof Num)`, then `(list-ref b 0)` will be a `Num`. So it looks like (2) is trying to call `append` on a `Num` and a `(Listof Num)`. Just like (1), it's the first argument that's the problem. And again, it looks like you meant to use `cons` instead.

The `cons` function has the signature `X (Listof X) -> (Listof X)`, where `X` can be any type like `Num`. If you use `cons` instead of `append` whenever you want to add a *single number* to a list, your code does what you expect:

```
;; check-numbers-size : Num (Listof Num) -> (Listof Num)
(define (check-numbers-size a b)
  (cond
    [(empty? b) (cons a b)]
    [(> a (list-ref b 0)) (cons (list-ref b 0) (cons a (rest b)))]
    [else (cons a b)]))
```